# Symfony2 - Updating this form to use AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony

As I'm still a beginner to Symfony2, I've been searching far and wide–including the official documentation for a simple tutorial or step by step guide on how to convert this simple form to use AJAX so I won't have to refresh the page.

Can someone guide me step by step on what goes in the Twig file and the Controller to make this happen?

Here is the original code for the Controller and Twig files:

**controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/form", name="form")
 */
public function formAction(Request $request)
{
    $article = new Article();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType(), $article);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Article saved');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('formsaved'));
    }

    return $this->render('Form/form.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}

/**
 * @Route("/formsaved", name="formsaved")
 */
public function formSavedAction()
{
    return $this->render('Form/formsaved.html.twig');
}
```

**form.html.twig**

```
{% block body %}
    {#{{ form(form) }}#}
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}

        {{ form_row(form.title) }}
        {{ form_row(form.body) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

**formsaved.html.twig**

```
{% block body %}

    {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('message') %}
    <p>{{ flashMessage }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**articletype form**

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType 
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('title', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Title'
    ))
            ->add('body', 'textarea')
            ->add('save', 'submit');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'article';
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Symfony2\FormBundle\Entity\Article'
    ));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a frontend matter than backend, so you should research some jQuery for example.

First, try to initiate AJAX on the form and try to replace it on a invalid submission

first tutorial from google: http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/851/cpsid_85119.html

you should also research `replaceWith()` jQuery function

Answer (score 0):

**1. Jquery**

.. assuming you know jquery

```
   $('body').on('click','#submitButton',  function(){ 
        //$(".loading").show();

        // getting the value of your input using the class (.) or id (#)
        var titleValue = $('#titleInput').val(); 

        //POST ajax
        var DATA = 'title=' + titleValue;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            // Routing.generate = fosjsroutingbundle You have to install this bundle            (generates routes in js )
            // or put the route manually, but it's quite dirty

            url: Routing.generate('your_symfony_route'),
            data: DATA,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                // $(".loading").hide();
                   $(".ajaxResponse").html(data);


                }
            });    

    });
```

**2. PHP**

In your controller

how to get the data from ajax query ?

```
  $request = $this->container->get('request');

        // ajax
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
           $title = $request->request->get('title');
```

How to persist the data ?

```
    $myArticle = new Article();
    $myArticle->setTitle($title);
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($myArticle);
    $em->flush();
```

How to return a response

```
    $mesage = new Response("your article was added to databse");
    return $message;
```